# WebRTC with raspberry pi zero?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc

I want low-latency streaming from my Raspberry Pi Zero to mobile phone. To my understanding, RTMP streaming is not supported on mobile browsers, HLS streaming is high latency, and webRTC is my best bet.

Does anyone know of a way to do webRTC streaming from the Zero? I have not found any options.

Answer (score 0):

Google's WebRtc implement support ARM&Linux, you can download the source and compile. There's some native simple(compared to iOS and Android) sample in it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=124204) post, it should be only available from Raspberry Pi 2 onwards, so Raspberry Pi Zero is not supported :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but fairly challenging. You need a WebRTC native stack (as opposed to the WebRTC stack available in the web browser where you only need to write Javascript that interfaces with the WebRTC API) and the Google reference implementation was really designed for web browsers, so it's not trivial to compile and getting running (that's after an 11GB repository checkout).

Take a look at https://alohacam.io -- WebRTC-based real-time video streaming, runs on any Raspberry Pi, including the Pi Zero (full disclosure: I'm one of the authors).